# String declaration error in if else

Tags: string, vba, ms-access-2007

I have Camp as string. When I write this code, I get an error:

`*Me.BoatDesc =< the expression you entered refer to an object that is close*`

**Here is my code**

```
private Sub Save_Click()

 Dim Camp As String

 If Me.BoatDesc = "Camp" Then

 Me.Amount = Me.Amount * 12

 End If
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: my forms runs ok..but not display the correct result only the value i enter on Amount text box display as result but not multiple.there is no text error but the if Me.BoatDesc ="Camp" then was selected when i point to it i see that error the one i say on my question

Comment: Try me.boatdesc.text = "Camp"

Comment: i tried it and the error says..."You cant reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus..im using Ms access 2007..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using VBA, not VB.Net. Here are some notes

Here is a simple form, it will be open when the code is run. The code will be run by clicking Save. Note that the default for an MS Access bound form is to save, so you might like to use a different name.

[image: a simple form]

This is the form in design view, note that there is a control named BoatDesc and another named Amount, as can only be seen from the property sheet.

[image: form design view]

The save button have an [Event Procedure], which is the code.

[image: save button property]

Note that the code belongs to Form2, the form I am working with, and the words Option Explicit appear at the top. This means I cannot have unnamed variables, so it is much harder to get the names wrong.

[image: code picture]

This is the code to be run by the save button.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Save_Click()
    ''Do not mix up strings, variables, controls and fields
    ''If you want to know if a control, BoatDesc, equals
    ''the string "camp", you do not need this
    ''Dim Camp As String

    If Me.BoatDesc = "Camp" Then
       Me.Amount = Me.Amount * 12
    End If
End Sub
```